# [Solved]How can I convert Cameraview.GetSnapShot() to Bitmap in a Maui mobile App?

Tags: c#, bitmap, maui, imagesource

This is my first pilot mobile application.
I have set up a Maui mobile application and it can capture and save the camera image as a file successfully.
My further intention is to manage the image file pixel by pixel(eg. to gray pixels).
It might need to convert the file to Bitmap class.
I am suffer in  generating a Bitmap as I usually do.
Below is my description.
The error messgae shows "System.PlatformNotSupportedException
Message=System.Drawing.Common is not supported on non-Windows platforms."

```
//  Namespace using (with System.Drawing.Common ):
    using System.Drawing;


    //Main code:
      string camPath = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory+"\\cam.jpg";
      string grayPath = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory + "\\gray.jpg";
      await Cameraview.SaveSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.JPEG, camPath);
//Error happen at the line below
      System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp =         (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(camPath);//Error happen here! How to rewrite this part? 
  System.Drawing.Bitmap newbmp = MakeGrayscale(bmp);
  newbmp.Save(grayPath);
  sampleImage.Source = null;
  sampleImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(grayPath);  

    //call functions:
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap MakeGrayscale(System.Drawing.Bitmap original)
    {
    // Build a new Bitmap 
    System.Drawing.Bitmap newBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

    // set  pixels to gray 
    for (int i = 0; i < original.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < original.Height; j++)
        {
            System.Drawing.Color originalColor = original.GetPixel(i, j);
            int grayScale = (int)((originalColor.R * 0.3) + (originalColor.G * 0.59) + (originalColor.B * 0.11));
            System.Drawing.Color newColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
            newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);
        }
    }

    return newBitmap;
    }

    public static byte[] BitmapToBytes(System.Drawing.Bitmap Bitmap)
    {
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = null;
    try
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        Bitmap.Save(ms, Bitmap.RawFormat);
        byte[] byteImage = new Byte[ms.Length];
        byteImage = ms.ToArray();
        return byteImage;
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        ms.Close();
    }
    }

    public static System.IO.Stream BytesToStream(byte[] bytes)
    {
    System.IO.Stream stream;
    try
    {
        stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return stream;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting, does it not do what you want? Does it raise an exception, if so what is the stacktrace? These details would help

Comment: Use SkiaSharp to do this

Comment: The error message is "System.PlatformNotSupportedException
  Message=System.Drawing.Common is not supported on non-Windows platforms. See https://aka.ms/systemdrawingnonwindows for more information."

Comment: Thanks to Jason. Your suggestion helps a lot. I have solved the problem.